# RHEL 5 Booting from Local Hardisk & SAN Harddisk via grub

Tags: rhel, multipath-storage

I had a RHEL machine booting from local disk.

Later I removed local disk & booted from a SAN disk and installed RHEL on it.

Now I have read about a grub.conf file:

```
root (hd0,0)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18.2-34-default root=/dev/hda1 vga=0x317 showopts
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.18.2-34-default
```

Grub stage1 boots from MBR and then when it goes to Stage2 it takes these entry parameters.

What is the simplest way to set and choose which OS the machine will boot from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When grub goes to stage 2, it will present the kernel selection menu.

The best way to configure this is to use either the SAN disk or the local disk as your MBR (master boot record) then update the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file to include both stanza entries from the local HDD and the SAN disk.

Then use the `default=0` entry to set the default OS kernel to load.

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
root (hd0,0)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18.2-34-default root=/dev/hda1 vga=0x317 showopts
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.18.2-34-default
### SAN stanza entry ###
root (sd0,0)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18.2-34-default root=/dev/sda1 vga=0x317 showopts
    initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.18.2-34-default
```

The second entry will be `default=1`.

**Note**
It may be better to boot from the SAN disk as you will be using the UEFI to load the fibre storage.

*Manually editing grub*

If you are unsure the local device number then you can go to the `command-line` entry when presented with the `grub` menu at boot time:

If you have the `hiddenmenu` setting in your `grub.conf` then it will say something similar to:

```
Booting from Red Hat 2.6.18.2-34... in 3 seconds ....
```

**Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to the menu:**

> ```
> Use the ^ and v keys to select which entry is highlighted.
> Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the
> commands before booting, 'a' to modify the kernel arguments
> before booting, or 'c' for a command-line.
> ```

At this point you can enter <kbd>c</kbd> and enter various root settings to get the correct disk setting:

```
grub> root (hd0,0)
 Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
```

**References**

[Using-grub-to-overcome-boot-problems](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/03/21/using-grub-to-overcome-boot-problems/)

Comment: In my case now i have 2 `/boot` one on san & other on local HDD .. Which / boot i should put this entry

Comment: Best practice will be to boot from the local disk, so once you have the `grub.conf` stanza entry from the SAN OS, then add it to the local disk grub.conf. Set your bios to use your local disk then test to ensure you can choose the SAN entry in the grub menu to load. Once this tests ok, I suggest you edit both grub.conf files so you have options.

Comment: May be os native name of disk may differ. Has to check with `e2label` & then maybe we can add associated entry for local hdd boot

Comment: If default 0 fails then does it will switch to default 1 automatically ??

Comment: No, you will have to manually override it through the console, when the menu loads, you will have an oportunity to interactively move the selection with the keyboard arrow keys then `enter`. At this point you can edit the configuration too. As soon as you move the cursor, the timeout will stop. Use `e` to edit the selection. Excelent article: [Grub boot edit](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/03/21/using-grub-to-overcome-boot-problems/)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I will mark useful & accept answer . i will try implement your inputs

Comment: Thanks - I have added additional useful info to the Answer.