# Migrating RHEL 6.x from Local Disk To SAN Disk

Tags: rhel, migration, san

I am running RHEL 6.x in my production and booting from local disk which is actually RAID 1 configured from BIOS. (IBM Blade Center H)
I wish to migrate this to SAN disk and perform SAN booting.

[This Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166367/rhel-5-booting-from-local-hardisk-san-harddisk-via-grub) in a way resembles to my problem.

I have /boot and /boot/efi as partition and rest of remaining space allocated to vg-lvm and OS FS is mapped.

/boot and /boot/efi is of size 1 GB each.

I am planning to clone /boot and /boot/efi on san disk with dd command.
May be I need to install grub on SAN disk as well.

and then I will perform pvmove and migrate OS FS on to SAN disk.

Is this the correct way to migrate OS disk to another ? Let's assume this is just DISK to DISK migration where the size of disk is different and exclude the SAN part.

Comment: The normal easiest process (taking SAN out of the equation) is just to clone the disk

Comment: so u suggest dd command will do that for entire disk ? My SAN disk size may be different. I will think about SAN booting later.